# How to middle two characters in a string in java is even

Tags: java

Given the String `"ABCDEFGHIJKLM"`, which contains an odd amount of letters, how can I remove the middle character? And when the string has an even amount of letter, how to remove the two middles ones?

Comment: " when the string is positive ..." ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You should note that you can't remove letters from a String in Java - you can only create a new string that has the letters that you want to keep.

Comment: Yes for example "ABCDEF" and the outcome would be just "ABEF"

Comment: [`String String.substring(int[, int])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) would help, let you read how it works since you are only asking how to do it...

Comment: What happens with "AB" and "ABCD"?

Comment: @PaulStatham "AB" would be "A" and "ABCD" would be "AD"

Comment: @PaulStatham, I would say in order "" and "AD" as it is said _And when the string has an even amount of letter, how to remove the two middles ones?_ EDIT : Supreme, then you are not following the requirement you gave ... "AB" as a even length so the two charater in the middle are "AB"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem

```
public class Test{

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String s = new String("ABCDf");
      System.out.println(s);
      int length = s.length();
      int mid = length / 2;
      s = (length % 2 != 0) ? (s.substring(0, mid) + s.substring(mid + 1, 
      s.length())) : (s.substring(0, mid - 1) + s.substring(mid + 1, s.length()));
      System.out.println(s);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A String object is immutable in java. Although you can remove the middle by using a stringbuilder.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "ABCDE";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string);
    if(string.length() % 2 != 0)
        sb.deleteCharAt(string.length()/2);
    else{
        int middle = string.length()/2 - 1;
        sb.deleteCharAt(middle);
        sb.deleteCharAt(middle);
    }
    string = sb.toString();  
}
```

Comment: For using the StringBuilder instead of `substring`, I had to upvote you!

Answer (score 1):

Also you can remove the middle by using StringBuffer and write simple easy 
Code below that.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLM";
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(string);

    if(string.length() % 2 != 0) {
        sb.deleteCharAt(string.length()/2);
    }

    string = sb.toString();  
    System.out.println("ans==" +string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take length at once so you can increase your performance , calculate length when you need .

```
public static void main(String...args) {
    String s = "ABCDEFGHIJKL";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    int length = s.length();
    if(length%2==0){
        sb.deleteCharAt(length/2);
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()/2);
    }else{
        sb.deleteCharAt(length/2);
    }
    s =sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    String str = "ABCDEF";
    System.out.println("string : " + str);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    int length= sb.length();
    if(length%2 != 0) {
        sb.deleteCharAt(length / 2);
    }
    else{
        sb.deleteCharAt((length / 2)-1);
        sb.deleteCharAt((length / 2)-1);
    }
    str = sb.toString();
    System.out.println("string : " + str);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="ABCDEFGHIJKLM";
System.out.println(str.substring(0,(str.length()-1)/2)+str.substring(str.length()/2+1,str.length()));
```

--

Explanation: the objective is to get the start and end indexes of the removed character(s). `(str.length()-1)/2` is the start index and `str.length()/2+1` is the end index for the 1 or 2 characters in the middle. Use these 2 integers to find the two substrings for concatenation.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println(word.charAt(length/2-1)+""+word.charAt(length/2));`

If you want to use two charAt in SystemOut,  dont use just +, use +""+.